# Plotar histogramas em grid com eixo Y fixo - R

Tags: r, histograma

Gostaria de plotar dois (ou mais) histograma em R onde o eixo Y prevalece um valor global para todos os histogramas. Não quero histogramas sobrepostos, mas sim um ao lado do outro. Quanto mais histograma eu estiver, vai acrescentando (à direita) do plot e todos com o eixo Y igual, pois preciso compara-lós.

Como por exemplo, nesta imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja se os códigos abaixo te ajudam.

Eu criei três amostras `x`, `y` e `z`, cada uma com distribuições normais diferentes, e plotei uma ao lado da outra. Perceba que primeiro criei `x` e `y`, só para depois adicionar `z`. Note também que a função `facet_grid` não exige nenhum parâmetro para deixar os eixos y na mesma escala.

```
# dados originais

n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n, mean=5, sd=3)
y <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1)

dados <- data.frame(grupos=rep(c("x", "y"), each=n), valores=c(x,y))

ggplot(dados, aes(x=valores)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=30) +
  facet_grid(~ grupos)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# adicionando outro grupo

z <- rnorm(n, mean=10, sd=2)
z <- data.frame(grupos="z", valores=z)

dados <- rbind(dados, z)

ggplot(dados, aes(x=valores)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=30) +
  facet_grid(~ grupos)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira deixar os eixos x todos na mesma escala, basta rodar o código abaixo, com a opção `scales = "free_x"` dentro de `facet_grid`:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=valores)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=30) +
  facet_grid(~ grupos, scales = "free_x")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: PERFEITO @marcus!!!

Comment: se eu quiser dividir por linha, 5 plots. Como ficaria?
No caso, tenho 10 histogramas, e quero que cada linha ficar com 5.

Comment: Substitua `facet_grid(~ grupos)` por `facet_wrap(~ grupos, nrow=2)`.

Comment: Perfeito! Vlw..